# Widget does not update properly after CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to display a progress indicator on my app on flutter while it's loading. If I don't use it, the app works properly and the data load, but when I add the progress indicator, after it disappears, the app shows only the containers' borders or colors, without the data in them. How can I solve?

Here's the code of the main page:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isLoaded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    DataSync data = DataSync();
    data.getInitialData();
    globals.isLoaded.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        isLoaded = true;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MainPage',
      home: Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, body:  inizializeApp() ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }

  Container inizializeApp() {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
            Color.fromARGB(255, 24, 26, 38),
            Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 0, 5),
          ])),
      //height: 500,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Center(
          child: isLoaded
              ? ListView(
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  children: const [
                    SizedBox(height: 70, child: WeatherWidgets()),
                    SizedBox(height: 70, child: WeekDayWidget()),
                    SizedBox(height: 50, child: DateWidget()),
                    DataWidget(),
                  ],
                )
              : const CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }
}
```

and the class where I update the globals containing the data:

```
ValueNotifier<WeatherForecastResult> forecastResultNotifier =
    ValueNotifier<WeatherForecastResult>(WeatherForecastResult.noParam());
ValueNotifier<int> selectedIndex = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
ValueNotifier<bool> isLoaded = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

class DataSync {
  Geolocation geolocation = Geolocation();
  WeatherForecastResult forecastResult = WeatherForecastResult.noParam();
  Weather weather = Weather();

  getInitialData() async {
    Position position = await geolocation.determinePosition();
    forecastResult =
        await weather.getForecast(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    forecastResultNotifier.value = forecastResult;
    isLoaded.value = true;
  }
}
```

Tried various widget for the progress indicator, but the problem doesn't disappear

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the problem - and failed! Could you check this simplified version (that should be complete in itself and run instantly) and try to reproduce the error? Or could you write a shortened version that is complete to run and reproduces the mistake? Then I would be happy to try to find out more!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

ValueNotifier<bool> globalIsLoaded = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isLoaded = false;

  Container initializeApp() {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
      child: isLoaded
          ? const Text('is loaded')
          : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ));
  }

  Container anotherInitializeApp() {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
      child: ValueListenableBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, bool valueFromGlobalIsLoaded,
            Widget? child) {
          return valueFromGlobalIsLoaded
              ? const Text('is loaded')
              : const CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
        valueListenable:
            globalIsLoaded, // <-- ignores local isLoaded, so you would not need an addListener
      ),
    ));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    DataSync data = DataSync();
    // data.getInitialData(); <-- moved it down after the addListener (but should not be decicive if this function is not super fast)
    globalIsLoaded.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        isLoaded = true;
      });
    });
    data.getInitialData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: initializeApp(), // try also: body: anotherInitializeApp(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DataSync {
  getInitialData() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    globalIsLoaded.value = true;
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```